# How to build an ANTLR code generation target

Tags: code-generation, antlr4

Is there an ANTLR4 version of "How to build an ANTLR code generation target". I know there is an ANTLR3 version but it seems to be way out of date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only real resource at this point is the repository for the [ANTLR 4 C# target](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs). It does include a [Creating Targets](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/blob/master/CreatingTargets.md) document, but it's not up-to-date and some sections (notably the Release Structure) is not correct. The Git history for the project shows how I implemented the C# target starting from the Java runtime.

You should note the following:

- Despite the removal of the AST and StringTemplate features from the ANTLR runtime, the ANTLR 4 runtime is very complicated due to the addition of the ALL(*) parsing algorithm. You should be *very* well versed in data structures, parallel programming, the semantics of Java code, and the semantics/libraries of your target language before attempting to create an ANTLR 4 target.
- Creation and maintenance of the C# target is tremendously simplified by using a modified version of [Sharpen](https://github.com/slluis/sharpen) to automate a large portion of the Java-to-C# conversion.

Comment: I think what you're saying is "tread lightly for there be dragons here" :) Thank you so much for your response. My goal was to create an Objective-C target for ANTLR4 but given your answer I might instead convert the Java code to Objective-C using j2objc <https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/>.